# How to install libltdl.so.3

Tags: fedora, software-installation, printer

I have Fedora 20, and am trying to install scanner software, 32-bit, for my Epson DX5000 printer. I get the messages:

```
[root@localhost:/home/Harry]$ rpm -Uvh iscan-2.29.3-1.usb0.1.ltdl3.i386.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
    libltdl.so.3 is needed by iscan-2.29.3-1.usb0.1.ltdl3.i386
[root@localhost:/home/Harry]$  yum install libltdl.so.3
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
No package libltdl.so.3 available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@localhost:/home/Harry]$
```

I have tried searching on the Internet for `libltdl.so.3`, but I find the results very confusing. Is it perhaps part of another package? Please can anyone help me?

---

Thanks for the answers so far. I think this is another time when I asked X when I should have asked Y. I already have `libtool` installed (see the screen shot) So now the question is: why does it say `libltdl.so.3 is needed` when `libtool` is already installed? Unless I have misunderstood what is going on, again.

```
[root@localhost:/home/Harry]$ yum install libtool-ltdl
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Package libtool-ltdl-2.4.2-23.fc20.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@localhost:/home/Harry]$
```

Also:

```
[root@localhost:/home/Harry]$ yum install libltdl7
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
No package libltdl7 available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@localhost:/home/Harry]$
```

Meta question: should I also change the title?

Comment: Looks like you want libltdl7.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you encounter a stray missing library file such as this one you can use the command `repoquery` to find out what package provides it.

#### Example

```
$ repoquery -q -f */libltdl.so*
libtool-ltdl-devel-0:2.4.2-16.fc19.x86_64
libtool-ltdl-0:2.4.2-23.fc19.x86_64
libtool-ltdl-devel-0:2.4.2-16.fc19.i686
libtool-ltdl-0:2.4.2-23.fc19.i686
libtool-ltdl-devel-0:2.4.2-23.fc19.i686
libtool-ltdl-0:2.4.2-16.fc19.i686
libtool-ltdl-devel-0:2.4.2-23.fc19.x86_64
libtool-ltdl-0:2.4.2-16.fc19.x86_64
```

I like to relax the query a bit and look for any `.so` files, so I've swapped the `.3` out for a `*`.

**NOTE:** The above is quering (`-q`) for files (`-f`) matching the pattern (`*/libltdl.so*`). The first star is important since the query is looking for matches against the full paths of the files within the RPMs stored on the various YUM repos your system is aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install libtool-ltdl:

```
yum install libtool-ltdl
```

Source: https://www.google.com/search?name=f&hl=en&q=libltdl.so.3

Comment: For headers: `libtool-ltdl-devel`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Fedora 21 (x64):

```
rpm -Uvh iscan-2.30.1-1.usb0.1.ltdl3.x86_64.rpm --nodeps

ln -s /usr/lib64/libltdl.so.7 /usr/lib64/libltdl.so.3
```

iscan seems to work fine with the newer library